# Object texture issue using three.js library

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I achieved to apply a texture to my 3D object using THREE.texture, but I still have an issue with the lateral face (see the link below). I don't know how to select the lateral face of my object...Do you have an idea on how to solve this ?

[Salmon Cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEM30.png)

```
        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
            console.log(item, loaded, total);
        };
        var texture = new THREE.Texture();
        var onProgress = function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
            }
        };
        var onError = function (xhr) {};

        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
        loader.load('/Scan/filet_1kg500-reposition-reduit_material_0.jpg', function (image) {
            texture.image = image;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        });
```